# How do a I add an attribute to <html> element (when using block theme)?

Tags: block-editor, html

I have a WordPress website that is using the Twenty Twenty-Two block theme (more specifically, a child theme of it). I want to edit the `<html>` root HTML element to add an attribute. I want this line of code:

```
<html lang="en-US">
```

... to change into this line of code:

```
<html lang="en-US" foo="bar">
```

Since this a block theme, there is no `header.php` file to edit. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use the [language_attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/language_attributes/) filter as before since the [template canvas](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/882687a54a8c36b37483c41c2056b05846664ecc/src/wp-includes/template-canvas.php#L14) in FSE contains:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
```

Add this code to the appropriate place in your theme or plugin:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'language_attributes', function($lang_attributes) {
    return "$lang_attributes foo=\"bar\"";
});
```